# Typescript Library : Incremental Hashing of Huge file at client side

Tags: angular, typescript, hash, cryptography, filehash

I need to have typescript/javascript based library which can support hashing when large file is provided to it. It should do the hashing in chunks rather than loading it entirely at once in the memory. I was using previously md5 hashing, but it cannot generate secure hashes all the time. So better to use SHA 512 hash based implementation.

I already saw few implementations regarding that on GitHub.
https://medium.com/@0xVaccaro/hashing-big-file-with-filereader-js-e0a5c898fc98. But this doesnt seems to be a library. I dont want to implement/copy -past the code. I just need 10-15 lines to setup the initialization and the rest of the hashing part should be done by library itself.

Can any body help me in this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37951557